# How to implement a loadingScreen correctly

Tags: iphone

I have built my loadingView and it looks good now. But I can't figure out the right moment to show and remove this loadingView. I use a NavigationController with my initial RootViewController which has a UIButton. When pressing the UIButton a new UIView appears, but this takes a few seconds because I'm loading some files from a server. So I want to show my loadingView during this time. I use the prepareForSegue()-Method and there I put the code to add my loading View like this

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:backgroundLoadingView];
```

and in the viewDidDisapperar I put this line of Code

```
[backgroundLoadingView removeFromSuperview];
```

The effect is, when I press the UIButton nothing happens for a few Seconds (because of loading the files)and the loadingView does not pop up (but I should), the new ViewController appears, the loadingView pops up for a second and disappears.

So it disappears in the right moment I guess, but it does not come up in the right moment. How can I handle this situation?

EDIT:
Here is my prepareForSegue-Method

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPointsOnMap"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Here is prepareForsegue()");
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:backgroundLoadingView];
        [self prepareJSONData:[self getJSONData]];
        [segue.destinationViewController setPointArray:thePointArray];
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you blocking the main thread with your network request?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show loading view while communicating with server you should add to window not to view controller.. like

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

window addSubView:backgroundLoadingView];

[window bringSubviewToFront:backgroundLoadingView];
```

Comment: I tried the solution with the window, i put this code to my prepareForSegue-Method and it has the same effect as described above. I also put a NSLog()-Statement as the first line in the prepareForSegue-Method, this is executed imidiently when i press my button but the second line where i add my subview is executed only when the secondViewController did appear.

Comment: i added my Subview in the viewDidloadMethod now, to see if `[self.navigationController.view]` is the right view wehre i add my subview and in fact it is. it appears immidiently as expected, but it does not appear in the prepareForSegue-Method.. what's wrong there?